# PXDatabase should accept PXDbType.Udt in Acumatica ERP

Tags: stored-procedures, erp, acumatica

How can I call a stored procedure in Acumatica via PXDataBase which has as input parameter User defined type?

For example, I have the following type:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[string_list_tblType] AS TABLE(
    [RefNbr] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RefNbr] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
```

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetListOfAPInvoices]
    @APInvoices as string_list_tblType readonly,
AS
BEGIN
    select * from APInvoice a where a.RefNbr in (select RefNbr  from @APInvoices)
END

and following fragment of C# code:

    var par = new SqlParameter("APInvoices", dt);
    par.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    par.TypeName = "dbo.string_list_tblType";
    par.UdtTypeName = "dbo.string_list_tblType";
    par.ParameterName = "APInvoices";

    PXSPParameter p1 = new PXSPInParameter("@APInvoices", PXDbType.Udt, par);
    var pars = new List<PXSPParameter> { p1};

    var results = PXDatabase.Execute(sqlCommand, pars.ToArray());
```

but when I execute my C# code I'm receiving error message:

```
UdtTypeName property must be set for UDT parameters
```

When I debugged with reflector class `PXSqlDatabaseProvider`, method 
`public override object[] Execute(string procedureName, params PXSPParameter[] pars)`
I noticed that

```
 using (new PXLongOperation.PXUntouchedScope(Thread.CurrentThread))
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

`command.Parameters.Items` has my method parameters, but item which is related to Udt type is null. I need to know how to pass user defined table type. Has anybody tried this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately UDT parameters are not supported in Acumatica's `PXDatabase.Execute(..)` method and there is no way to pass one to a stored procedure using the built-in functionality of the platform.

Besides, when writing data-retrieval procedures like the one in your example, you should acknowledge that BQL-based data-retrieval facilities do a lot of work to match company masks, filter out records marked as `DeletedDatabaseRecord` and apply some other internal logic. If you chose to fetch data with plain select wrapped into a stored procedure you bypass all this functionality. Hardly is this something that you want to achieve.

If you absolutely want to use a stored procedure to get some records from the database but don't want the above side-effect, one option is to create an auxiliary table in the DB and select records into it using a procedure. Then in the application you add a DAC mapped to this new table and use it to get data from the table by means of `PXSelect` or similar thing.

Coming back to your particular example of fetching some `ARInvoice`s by the list of their numbers, you could try using dynamic BQL composition to achieve something like this with Acumatica data access facilities.

Comment: One of the reason i've seen people attempt to use stored procedures is that they don't know how to achieve what they need in BQL. I always try to steer people away from this idea, and to try to use BQL the way it was intended to be used. Also very important to remember that the stored proc is DB specific, and won't work independently between MySQL and MS SQL like a BQL statement...

Comment: Hi Gabriel. Thank you for your comment. I achieved what I want with BQL and my solution is workable. I just faced another chalenge. BQL statements work so slowly that client become furious. And only way to improve perfomance for me available now is usage of stored procedures.